# How to implement onkeydown method to broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to track volume key down when screen was off. How can I put my code in on receive method?

I want to turn on flashlight when user pressed volume down key and when screen goes off.

**MyReceiver.java :**

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private boolean screenOff;

  @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

        screenOff = true;
        // Log.i("via Receiver","Normal ScreenOFF" );
     } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        screenOff = false;
     } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER)) {

    }

    Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
    context.startService(i);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set event listener inside `onReceive()`. Try like this

```
setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
  @Override public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        if (screenOff) {
          // turn on torch
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: But this only works if your app is in the foreground, right?